# How to optimize the building time with LlamaIndex by storing an agent or a toolkit?

Tags: python, chatbot, langchain, py-langchain, llama-index

I'm currently building a chatbot agent with `llama_index` to take benefit of a dataset of 13 000 documents I have. However, making the toolkit to then build the agent takes a lot of time (4h) because I have to load the indexes to make the actual toolkit. Is there a way to store the toolkit on a disk to just load the toolkit and being able to build the agent way more quickly ? Or store the agent on a disk or somewhere ?

I am able to store the graph and the indexes but I can't see a way to store the toolkit.

Here is my code that works fine but slowly.

```py
def generate_chatbot():
    # Load indexes from s3
    index_set = {}
    urls=[]
    for i in range (130):
        urls.append("canada/"+str(i))
    for url in urls:
        sc_express = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir='myS3/'+url, fs=s3)
        express_entry_index = load_index_from_storage(sc_express)
        #The step that is taking a lot of time and that I want to avoid
        index_set[url] = express_entry_index

    # set summary text for each doc
    index_summaries = [f"Webpage {url} url" for url in urls]
    # set number of output tokens
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, max_tokens=2048))
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor)
    # define a list index over the vector indices
    # allows us to synthesize information across each index
    graph = ComposableGraph.from_indices(
        GPTListIndex, 
        [index_set[y] for y in urls], 
        index_summaries=index_summaries,
        service_context=service_context
    )

    decompose_transform = DecomposeQueryTransform(
        llm_predictor, verbose=True
    )

    # define custom query engines
    custom_query_engines = {}
    for index in index_set.values():
        query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
        query_engine = TransformQueryEngine(
            query_engine,
            query_transform=decompose_transform,
        )
        custom_query_engines[index.index_id] = query_engine
    custom_query_engines[graph.root_id] = graph.root_index.as_query_engine(
        response_mode='tree_summarize',
        verbose=True,
    )

    # construct query engine
    graph_query_engine = graph.as_query_engine(custom_query_engines=custom_query_engines)

    # graph config
    graph_config = IndexToolConfig(
        query_engine=graph_query_engine,
        name=f"Graph Index",
        description="useful  when asking global questions ",
        tool_kwargs={"return_direct": True, "return_sources": True},
        return_sources=True
    )

    index_configs = []
    for url in urls:
        tool_config = IndexToolConfig(
            query_engine=query_engine, 
            name=f"Vector Index {url}",
            description=f"useful for when you want to answer queries about the {url} ",
            tool_kwargs={"return_direct": True}
        )
        index_configs.append(tool_config)

    toolkit = LlamaToolkit(
        index_configs=index_configs+ [graph_config],
        graph_configs=[graph_config]
    )


    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")
    prompt = "Hello! You are here to assist me with detailed information for immigrants to Canada. Please refrain from mentioning or discussing any external resources. Instead, kindly provide the relevant content directly and ask for more details if you can't provide relevant content. Don't mention additional sources that are websites. Always ask for more details so that the next answer could be better. Please ensure that the information shared is accurate, up-to-date, and reliable. Don't say to always check the informations on the governement websites. Thank you!"

    llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.1, model="gpt-4")
    agent_chain = create_llama_chat_agent(
        toolkit,
        llm,
        memory=memory,
    )

    return {"agent_chain":agent_chain,"firstMessage":True,"prompt":prompt}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where it's spending that time? If not, start with that.

Comment: Yeah it's spending that time while loading the indexes here : express_entry_index = load_index_from_storage(sc_express) and the rest is very quick

Comment: And within that function? What does your profiler say?

Comment: (Anyway, have you tried to just `pickle` the object you want to persist?)

Comment: The function load_index_from_storage isn't mine it's a function from the llama_index library. I just tried to pickle the object but it's not possible I guess as I get the error TypeError: cannot pickle 'builtins.CoreBPE' object

Comment: And a profiler will show you where library code is spending time, which is what I was asking...

Comment: I have runned the profiler with less files (for i in range(2)) just so that it's not too long but here is the result, I don't know what to do with these results and how it could help me though. EDIT : It's way too long I can't upload it here but I have copied it here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Xj8ngrPZBW2FxjcL6JlhizxIXX_pknzEsxJiqCee3Uo/edit

Comment: That helps a bit (next time run `-m cProfile -s time` so the results are sorted by time and not name) - it looks like a lot of time is spent waiting for locks, and secondly decoding what I assume is JSON. If the toolchain supports a faster JSON decoder like `orjson`, that could help...

Comment: did you resolve your performance issue? OOTB LlamaIndex doesn't scale afaik. Most operations are sync/sequential. Caching the Agents and Toolkit to disk isn't going to solve the performance issue caused by the index load. I suggest downloading the index files from S3 to local disk. Then set your `StorageContext` to the local disk path before calling load index. This should improve load times. However, a large index will probably still be slow when using the default simple index providers.